# Ubuntu login screen goes blank

Tags: 14.04, login

I have ubuntu 14.04 LTS and Windows vista .. both 32-bit.. dual-boot.. running on my laptop HP Compaq 6710b.

When I start the PC, the grub loader appears, then I select Ubuntu.. the Ubuntu login screen does not appear..but the login system sound plays and when I enter the root password.. the ubuntu home desktop appears..and from then on it works normally..

The issue is only the ubuntu login screen does not appear and I am entering my root password looking at a blank screen each time I boot :)

Please help me resolve this issue.

Comment: Did you install a closed source driver?

Comment: I have no idea what a closed source driver is.. I am new to Ubuntu.. and btw I did not install any driver.. I only did apt-get update and upgrade so far..

Comment: Did you go to "Additional Drivers" and install the Nvidia or AMD driver?